# Who recorded “Mother of all Bombs" explosion from ground level?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, military

The United States dropped "the mother of all bombs," the largest non-nuclear device it has ever unleashed in combat, on a network of caves and tunnels used by Islamic State in eastern Afghanistan on Thursday; April 13th of 2017.

I saw [the video](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/bomb-video-afghanistan-pentagon-footage-moab-twitter-us-department-of-defence-a7683731.html), Explosion video was released, It is from ground view i.e ground level explosion.

Who recorded “Mother of all Bombs" explosion from ground level?

Comment: If this is not appropriate question for this SE, then please suggest one.

Comment: I dont think that this is the right SE or that there is even a right SE for this question... sorry. That being said, are you sure that video is from the actual attack? I would guess thats actually a recording from a test run. Can you link to where you got that picture from?

Comment: Since it's not `about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center`, it's off-topic here. You can try [Photography.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com), provided it's [on-topic there](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Still dont really think its a fit for the site, sorry. Also please link to your source for the picture

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I added independent UK video link to avoid confusion in my post. Is that enough or anything else required?

Comment: @Sringam the video from independent does not show ground level video of the MOAB detonated in Afghanistan.  This is not the correct site for this question.  I suggest taking a breath and reconsider what your question is, and where an appropriate place to ask it is.

Comment: Just FYI, the ground level blast you see is from the 2003 public test. I don't think anyone was at ground level (1 mile, 1.6km blast radius), nor was the site a flat terrain but a mine within a mountain.

Comment: either by chance, or the person(s) recording it had advanced knowledge of its deployment, its explosion radius, its location, and its timing, to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/04/13/politics/afghanistan-isis-moab-bomb/):

> A GBU-43/B Massive Ordnance Air Blast Bomb (MOAB), nicknamed the
>   "mother of all bombs," was dropped **at 7:32 p.m. local time**

Google tells us that sunset was [at about 6:25 PM](https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=afghanistan%20sunset) (local time), so I assume that was quite dark (Civil Twilight 18:28 - 18:55 on 15th April, [source](https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/afghanistan/kunduz)) when the bombing took place. I think only the footage from air is of the actual bombing, all others being from some previous tests (when there was more light).

Also, it seems that the explosion caught from the air is much larger that what is shows afterwards. But this is in an analysis for [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/).